# Calculating YoY YTD in DAX

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

Scenario:
Take a fundraising event (e.g. Virgin London Marathon), which has an event start date, say in 2017.  This event receives donations.  The donations can be made in the year before, the year of the event or even the year after.

I need to report the total donations received for that event by event year, not the year the donations were made.  This needs to be available from a cube based on an SSAS tabular model.  This in itself is not a problem - I have a fact containing the donation amounts, and an event dimension with the event year.  so selecting VLM for event year 2017 aggregates all donations made to VLM 2017 correctly.

The problem I'm having is how to report on the previous event year when selecting the current event year.  So what I want to see when selecting VLM 2017 by event year is one column showing the amount donated in 2017 (regardless of when the donations occurred), and another column containing the total donation amount for the previous event year, i.e. VLM 2016, again, regardless of when the donations occurred.

I think a new fact may be needed for this - FactEvent, and a measure added to this fact, however I'm struggling to build a DAX formula to calculate the previous event year amount.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a `DAX` formula called `previousyear()` which may help. If you have a column named `Event Year` a measure with `-1` in the formula could auto select the year before by simply subtracting one from `Event Year`

Comment: Thanks John.  It turned out to be a bit more complicated :-)SUMX (
VALUES ('Event'[Event Year]),
CALCULATE (
[Donation Amount],
ALL ( 'Date'),
FILTER (
ALL ( 'Event'[Event Year] ),
VALUE('Event'[Event Year] )
= EARLIER ( 'Event'[Event Year]) -1
)
)
)